# "show 13 more comments"

Tags: feature-request

[Note: I don't know if this is a general comment about the Stack Exchange network at large or something that is controllable site-by-site.]

When a comment thread gets too long, stack exchanges seem to use a rule for determining which comments are shown and which are hidden (perhaps chronologically by "has greater than 1 upvote").

I find hidden comments a bit annoying, especially on mobile. Typically, there's a flow to the comments, but reading them as shown (without clicking "show X more comments") gives me just some highlights. While comments aren't meant to serve as a secondary conversation between members, they sometimes *are*, or they hold multi-comments (i.e. parts 1-3) from a single user. Having to click to show the non-upvoted comments is awkward from a reader's standpoint. On mobile, comments suddenly appear above and/or below your current view.

So, why do we have this functionality? Is it really helping readers by showing them just the most popular comments? And to the main point: Is there a way to automatically show or hide all comments when a page loads?

[Update]
This type of question apparently has quite a history on the Stack Exchange network. See [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/55020/add-a-show-more-comments-button-to-the-top-of-a-list-of-comments) and [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/24490/can-we-get-an-indication-comments-are-hidden-between-the-comments) and here. The short answer is that you can [change some functionality for your own computer](https://stackapps.com/questions/6091/stack-overflow-extras-sox) if you're willing to do a little bit of coding. So, carry on, then.

Comment: Your question seems to be more appropriately asked at [Meta Stack Exchange](https://meta.stackexchange.com/) instead of here.